# Remove one of two possible values from a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list such as

```
furniture = [desk, Lamp, Chair, shelf]
```

Some of them are capitalized for a reason. The values of this list are subject to change but I want to be able to say:

```
furniture.remove(chair) or furniture.remove(Chair)
```

But if it is one and not the other, it pulls an error as it should because that is the result of a list.remove(x) if the x does not exist in that list. How can i bypass this issue?

Either with the capitalization, or with deleting one of two possibilities in a single list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `try` and `except`:

```
try:
   furniture.remove('chair')
except ValueError:
   furniture.remove('Chair')
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, been staring at this too long. I could not for the life of me remember what the terms in Python were. This is what I was looking for Thanks so much!

Comment: @cbbcbail -- As a side note, put the one you expect to be more common in the `try` part and the less common one in the `except` block.

Comment: ya, will make it run faster. Thanks!

Comment: One question about try and except: When it does get the exception, will it immediately go to that or will it run the rest of the code in try first?

Comment: @cbbcbail -- It will immediately go to `except`.  If you want other code to be run, you need to look into the `else` and `finally` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work? Note that it creates a new list as opposed to modifying your original:

```
In [4]: furniture = ['desk', 'Lamp', 'Chair', 'shelf']

In [5]: [item for item in furniture if item.lower() != 'chair']
Out[5]: ['desk', 'Lamp', 'shelf']
```

Or with `capitalize`:

```
In [6]: [item for item in furniture if item.capitalize() != 'Chair']
Out[6]: ['desk', 'Lamp', 'shelf']
```

However as @mgilson points out, this will remove **all** occurrences in your list, not just the first. His answer is much cleaner, but here is a completely nonsensical/unnecessary way you could remove just the first match:

```
def first(l, value):
    new_l = [item for item in enumerate(l) if item[1].lower() == value]
    if new_l:
        return min(new_l)[1]
    return

# Original list
furniture = ['desk', 'Lamp', 'chair', 'shelf', 'chair', 'chair', 'Chair', 'Chair']

print 'Original:', furniture
for word in ('chair', 'dogs'):
  f = first(furniture, word)
  if f:
    furniture.remove(f)
  print 'Removing:', word, furniture
```

Output:

```
Original: ['desk', 'Lamp', 'chair', 'shelf', 'chair', 'chair', 'Chair', 'Chair']
Removing: chair ['desk', 'Lamp', 'shelf', 'chair', 'chair', 'Chair', 'Chair']
Removing: dogs ['desk', 'Lamp', 'shelf', 'chair', 'chair', 'Chair', 'Chair']
```

Comment: This might not be a problem, but this will give different results if OP has multiple `chair` in the list.

Comment: shouldn't be multiples in my list, however I don't want to capitalize it I was looking for the simple try and except. thanks though!

Comment: @cbbcbail No worries :) Note that this doesn't actually capitalize anything - it just uses that as a way to compare the items in an even manner (so if `item` is `desk`, the comparison becomes `if 'Desk' != 'Chair'`, which will evaluate `True` and add a non-capitalized `desk` to the list).

Comment: Ya, this isn't quite what 'm looking for.

Comment: @mgilson I think I'm just slow this morning - could you give an example? I'll try to update (although I think it may be moot at this point :) ).

Comment: `list.remove` will only remove the *first* occurance whereas your example will remove *every* occurance.  e.g. `['chair','chair']` with yours becomes `[]`, but with `list.remove` it would just become `['chair']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if chair in furniture:
    furniture.remove(chair)
if Chair in furniture:
    furniture.remove(Chair)
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this but it becomes extremely convoluted and this is a simplified version of my actual code. Thanks though.